# Is it possible to capture standard deviation from %%timeit -o?

Tags: jupyter-notebook, ipython, jupyter-lab

I get average time to take running function but cannot get standard deviation.

```
import random
def average_py(n):
    s = 0
    for i in range(n):
        s += random.random()
    return s / n
n = 10_000_000
```

```
result_py = %timeit -o average_py(n)
```

> 670 ms ± 2.98 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

```
print(result_py.average)
```

> 0.6704248709886867

I already checked [ipython document](http://man.hubwiz.com/docset/iPython.docset/Contents/Resources/Documents/api/generated/IPython.core.magics.execution.html).

Comment: Playing around, I find that `result=%%timeit ...` isn't allowed (by python syntax), but `%%timeit -o ....` puts a `result` object in the `Out`, from where it's attributes can be accessed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is accessible through `result_py.stdev`.

```
In [1]: import random
   ...: def average_py(n):
   ...:     s = 0
   ...:     for i in range(n):
   ...:         s += random.random()
   ...:     return s / n
   ...: n = 10_000_000

In [2]: result_py = %timeit -o average_py(n)
1.37 s ± 40.5 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

In [3]: result_py.stdev
Out[3]: 0.040515329046983364
```